# Foundry switch doesn't ping

Tags: switch, ping

we have one foundry switches, but we cannot ping the switch, but the switch works well, and we can ping any other device connect to it! we reset the switch couple of time, but the problem still remained and we cannot ping the switch!

where is the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: Does it have a console port?

Comment: yes, it has console port, what should I do? we cannot telnet to switch either

Comment: Plug in via the console port and see what's going on with it, like blocking remote access.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like either you don't know what the IP address of the switch is or else the management interface of the switch is on a VLAN that you don't currently have access to. Might either of those be the case?

Comment: that`s impossible, because this happen 2 days ago and before that we we can easily ping that device

Comment: @user19049: You may have changed the management IP address of the switch without saving the configuration. Then, a switch restart will be enough to revert to the old IP address. The best option I think is to try to remember what has changed during or before those two days.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this behaviour on a Cisco switch, where the management address was attached to a VLAN interface and there were no active ports in that VLAN.

I'd use the console port to verify that the switch is healthy, check the logs if there's anything of interest and double-check that the Foundry's management IP is on a (virtual or real) interface that is active.